# Cross browser grayscale not working

Tags: css, cross-browser

So I have this google map which needs to have a black and white effect on it, it works in the following chrome,edge and firefox but safari and ie it's a no go.

Originally my css looked like the following, I have looked around and the only real solution which people said worked was the filter: url('....') but for me it is not working. Any one with a solution would be greatly appreciated. p.s I would prefer if this was done with css anyone saying it can be done with api I'd rather not go down that route.

```
#LocationMap {
width: 100%;
height: 400px;
float: left;
filter: url(data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter i…0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale);
filter: gray;
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
-webkit-transition: all .6s ease;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0 2000px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use styled maps, here info for implementation:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling

If you want, you can find tons of ready style here:
https://snazzymaps.com/